# How to use aliases in MySQL natural full outer join?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Here is my code,when I run this, it will show an error: every derived table must have an alias, however I try different methods to add aliases, it just doesn't work.Anyone know how to fix it ?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM student s WHERE dept_name='Comp.Sci')
NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM takes t WHERE semester='Spring' AND YEAR=2009);
```

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer join

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql there is not  full outer join but you could use union  (eventually show us a proper datasample for suggest the better query union)

```
    SELECT * FROM student s WHERE dept_name='Comp.Sci'
    union
    SELECT * FROM takes t WHERE semester='Spring' AND YEAR=2009
```

For your code  you need  an alias for each table  eg: for each from()

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT * FROM student s WHERE dept_name='Comp.Sci') t1
    JOIN ........
    (SELECT * FROM takes t WHERE semester='Spring' AND YEAR=2009) t2;
```

anyway if you have same columns name in the derived  tabke you cant use *  (select all) but use explicit column name and alias for avoid ambiguity